# Facebook Graph API - running into field query/search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I return Facebook IDs of my friends that use a certain application?

If you go to https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=friends_using_app&app_id=2439131959 you'll see a list of your friends who have this application (on the far right)

I'm trying to either read the connections or search for the connections based on the social graph using the graph api.

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=friends_using_app&app_id=6628568379` doesn't work

`https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=?type=friends_using_app&app_id=6628568379` doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you have to use FQL: it can not be done with the graph API in its present state. Try this FQL:

`SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user = 1 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = {userid})`